# How to conect data scraping with google sheets

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets, python-3.8

i have this code from a web scraping

```
from smart_sensor_client.smart_sensor_client import SmartSensorClient
import json
import requests
import pprint
DEFAULT_SETTINGS_FILE = 'settings.yaml'


def run_task(settings_file=DEFAULT_SETTINGS_FILE) -> bool:

    # Create the client instance
    client = SmartSensorClient(settings_file=settings_file)

    # Authenticate
    if not client.authenticate():
        print('Authentication FAILED')
        return False

    # Get list of plants
    plants = client.get_plant_list()

    # Iterate the plant list and print all assets therein
    for plant in plants:
    
        # Get list of assets
        response = client.get_asset_list(organization_id=client.organization_id)
        if len(response) == 0:
            print('No assets in this plant')
        else:
            for asset in response:
                print(asset["assetName"],':',asset["lastSyncTimeStamp"])
               ...
```

And the following answer. json that i filter with the information i am interested in.

```
Ventilador FCH 11 : 2020-06-11T09:48:45Z
VTL SVA1 : 2020-06-11T10:20:43Z
Dardelet PV-1 : 2020-06-11T09:58:14Z
CANDLOT 1 (MOTOR N°2) : 2020-06-11T10:37:39Z
PC N°1 S1/2A : 2020-06-11T10:57:34Z
VTL SVA2 : 2020-06-11T11:31:08Z
Ventilador FCH 6 : 2020-06-11T11:43:28Z
Vibrotamiz Tolva Tampon  : 2020-06-11T11:44:43Z
Ventilador FCH 10 : 2020-06-11T11:08:03Z

Task SUCCESS
```

I would like to paste this on a google sheet but i dont know how if its possible. Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

Comment: thats for google docs. Not google sheets

Comment: sorry, too quick on the google: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python